# TestNG parameter- how to run mulitple test cases concurrently

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, parameters, testng, testng.xml

i am trying to run two same test cases concurrently using chrome broswer, how do i achieve it?

the code below i tried, it opens two browsers and one of test case did not start. any help? thanks

```
<suite name="Suite">

    <test name="ToolsQA1">

 <parameter name="sUsername" value="testuser_1"/>

 <parameter name="sPassword" value="Test@123"/>

 <classes>

     <class name="automationFramework.TestngParameters" />

 </classes>

    </test>
 <test name="ToolsQA2">

 <parameter name="sUsername" value="testuser_2"/>

 <parameter name="sPassword" value="Test@999"/>

 <classes>

     <class name="automationFramework.TestngParameters" />

 </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

My TestngParameters class
this is my class package, i have added

```
package automationFramework;

public class TestngParameters{

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

    @Beforesuite
    public void testng() throws InterruptedException
    {   
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver.get("https://www.testing.com"); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Beforetest
    @Parameters({"sUsername","sPassword"})
    public void declareaccount(String sUsername, String sPassword) throws InterruptedException 
    {   
        WebElement sname = driver.findElement(By.name("FullName"));
        sname.clear();
        sname.sendKeys(sUsername);
        WebElement passwordname = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        spassword.clear();
        spassword.sendKeys(sPassword);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the `TestngParameters` class?

Comment: sorry i am pretty new, do you mean this <classes>

     <class name="automationFramework.TestngParameters" />

 </classes>  ??  i am using same class file for both testname

Comment: Please update the question with add the `TestngParameters` class

Comment: ok it is updated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Add one attribute in XML file on suite level

```
<suite name=”  “ parallel=”tests” thread-count =”2”>
```

the attribute parallel="tests" - it will run the tests

the attribute thread-count="2" - how many test you want to run

Comment: i getting this error when i input the attributes org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 44; Element type "suite" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".   did i did it wrongly?

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/sessions-parallel-run-and-dependency-in-selenium.html check this link